# Why google map not showing right direction in android app?

Tags: android, google-maps

Google maps doesn't show me the right direction. If im staying on a street, holding my phone directioned straight ahead, maps is showing me that i'm actually looking 30� to the left.I don't know why its giving wrong latitude,longitude.

Please any help greatly appreciated....
thanks..

Comment: Are you asking about a program you've written, or the official Google Maps app?  If the latter, you should ask at the Android StackExchange.

Comment: thanks @kevin for your response. Yes I am asking about my code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know either, unless you post some code.  I recommend you do that or your question will likely be closed.

A wrong bearing and a wrong lat/long are two very different things.  Since you describe the wrong bearing in more detail, I'll assume that's what you meant.

First, make sure you're not near any large metal objects.  If you're in a city, that might be a problem.  My phone's compass is off by 60 degrees when it's on my computer desk.

Second, make sure your compass is calibrated.  You can do this by moving the device around in a figure-eight fashion.  There are several videos on YouTube that show how to do this.

Third, are you compensating for magnetic declination?  If so, are you sure you're adjusting in the right direction?

Comment: Hi, I think my question is little bit confusing,  I have one tab on which i have put display route of particular GPS device. Since currently i dont have GPS device so i am using my phone. I am able to display path on map but sometime device location is not correctly displayed (centre of the road). It display towards side of the road. I want to check what could be the issue for this and how to correct it.

Comment: It's not unusual for your GPS location to be off by tens of meters, especially in a city.  The best civilian GPS receivers only provide about 3.5 meter accuracy.